# Tools for visual studio

Tags: c, visual-studio

I would like to know what are the tools that facilitate the work of the programmer. Can you  advise me programs for detect memory leaks? I  use Visual Studio C 7.1. If you know you give a link where I can download the appropriate program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try next programs:
Deleaker (Windows),
Valgrind (Linux),
CheckPointer

Comment: Use deleaker - is the most powerful tool.

Answer (score 1):

I use ANTS from RedGate:

http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/features/features-list

They have both a performance and a memory profiler, and support all versions of the .Net framework.

You are using an older version of Visual Studio, unfortunately, as the Performance Profiler built into some editions of 2010 is pretty good these days.

Answer (score 1):

See our [family of tools for the C language](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/LanguageTools/CTools.html).   These include SmartDifferencers, Clone Detection, Test Coverage and Profiling and [CheckPointer](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/MemorySafety), a tool for finding memory errors of all kinds.